# Find out which part of object an item belongs to

Tags: underscore.js

I need to find out which array from an object an item belongs to, **"buildings"** or **"gardens"**;

So, say I have this...

```
var id = '122'
```

Which corresponds to

```
a.data.gardens.item_id = 122
```

I need to find out whether it belongs to "buildings" or "gardens so I can use it like this.

```
if (result === 'buildings') {
    // Do this
} else if (result === 'gardens') {
    // Do this
}
```

I would like to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as it's already being used heavily in this project, but it's not essential if a vanilla JS solution is simpler.

**Here is the object**

```
var a = {
   'object_handle': 'handle',
   'something_else': 'ladela',
   'some_other_thing': 'other thing',
   'data':{
      'object_id': 120,
      'buildings':[
         {
            'item_id':120,
            'title':'Some title',
         }, 
         {
            'item_id':121,
            'title':'Some other title'
         }
      ],
      'some_other_thing': 'other thing',
      'gardens':[
         {
            'item_id':122,
            'title':'Some title'
         }, 
         {
            'item_id':123,
            'title':'Some other title'

         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**some**](http://underscorejs.org/#some) to check the collections:

```
var id = 122;

var isGarden = _.some(a.data.gardens, {item_id: id});
var isBuilding = _.some(a.data.buildings, {item_id: id});
```

Comment: This works perfectly. The answer before used ._findWhere, is there a reason you favoured _.some()? is it more performant?

Comment: Some returns true or false, findWhere returns an object. As you only wanted to know if the object was in the collection I chose some.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using underscore:

```
var find_id=122;

//here a is the object defined above in the OP question.

if(_.findWhere(a.data.buildings, {item_id: find_id})){
    console.log("buildings")
} else if(_.findWhere(a.data.gardens, {item_id: find_id})){
    console.log("gardens")
}
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/03fzjruw/)